# Rsync how to exclude all arch without amd64

Tags: scripting, rsync

Have make little script on Linux that's intended to rsync, excluding all arch without amd64, but it is downloading all arch's.

What is wrong with the script?

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is a sample mirroring script.
HOME="/tmp/http"
TARGET="${HOME}/debian"
TMP="${HOME}/.tmp/debian"
LOCK="/tmp/rsync-debian.lock"
ARCH_EXCLUDE="alpha arm armel armhf hppa hurd-i386 i386 ia64 kfreebsd-amd64 kfreebsd-i386 m68k mipsel mips powerpc s390 s390x sh sparc source"
rsync_exclude=""
for item in $ARCH_EXCLUDE; do
    rsync_exclude="$rsync_exclude --exclude $item"
done

# NOTE: You'll probably want to change this or remove the --bwlimit setting in
# the rsync call below
BWLIMIT=10000

SOURCE="rsync://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/"

[ ! -d "${TARGET}" ] && mkdir -p "${TARGET}"
[ ! -d "${TMP}" ] && mkdir -p "${TMP}"

exec 9>"${LOCK}"
flock -n 9 || exit

if ! stty &>/dev/null; then
    QUIET="-q"
fi

rsync $rsync_exclude \
    -rtlvH \
    --safe-links \
    --bwlimit=${BWLIMIT} \
    --delete-after --progress \
    -h ${QUIET} \
    --timeout=600 \
    --contimeout=120 -p \
    --delay-updates \
    --no-motd \
    --temp-dir="${TMP}" \
    ${SOURCE} \
    "${TARGET}"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes have fixed my issue with bash script have shared this : https://github.com/liberodark/linux-mirroring

reproduced here:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is a sample mirroring script.
HOME="/tmp/http"
TARGET="${HOME}/debian"
TMP="${HOME}/.tmp/debian"
LOCK="/tmp/rsync-debian.lock"
#EXCLUDE="${alpha arm armel armhf hppa hurd-i386 i386 ia64 kfreebsd-amd64 kfreebsd-i386 m68k mipsel mips powerpc s390 s390x sh sparc source}"

# NOTE: You'll probably want to change this or remove the --bwlimit setting in
# the rsync call below
BWLIMIT=10000

SOURCE="rsync://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/"

[ ! -d "${TARGET}" ] && mkdir -p "${TARGET}"
[ ! -d "${TMP}" ] && mkdir -p "${TMP}"

exec 9>"${LOCK}"
flock -n 9 || exit

if ! stty &>/dev/null; then
    QUIET="-q"
fi

rsync --exclude 'source*' \
    --exclude '*.debian.tar.xz' \
    --exclude '*.orig.tar.xz' \
    --exclude '*.orig.tar.bz2' \
    --exclude '*.dsc' \
    --exclude '*_arm64.deb' \
    --exclude '*_armel.deb' \
    --exclude '*_armhf.deb' \
    --exclude '*_i386.deb' \
    --exclude '*_mips.deb' \
    --exclude '*_mips64el.deb' \
    --exclude '*_mipsel.deb' \
    --exclude '*_ppc64el.deb' \
    --exclude '*_s390x.deb' \
    --exclude 'binary-arm64*' \
    --exclude 'binary-armel*' \
    --exclude 'binary-armhf*' \
    --exclude 'binary-i386*' \
    --exclude 'binary-mips*' \
    --exclude 'binary-mips64el*' \
    --exclude 'binary-mipsel*' \
    --exclude 'binary-ppc64el*' \
    --exclude 'binary-s390x*' \
    --exclude 'installer-arm64*' \
    --exclude 'installer-armel*' \
    --exclude 'installer-armhf*' \
    --exclude 'installer-i386*' \
    --exclude 'installer-mips*' \
    --exclude 'installer-mips64el*' \
    --exclude 'installer-mipsel*' \
    --exclude 'installer-ppc64el*' \
    --exclude 'installer-s390x*' \
    --exclude 'Contents-arm64*' \
    --exclude 'Contents-armel*' \
    --exclude 'Contents-armhf*' \
    --exclude 'Contents-i386*' \
    --exclude 'Contents-mips*' \
    --exclude 'Contents-mips64el*' \
    --exclude 'Contents-mipsel*' \
    --exclude 'Contents-ppc64el*' \
    --exclude 'Contents-s390x*' \
    --exclude 'Contents-udeb-arm64*' \
    --exclude 'Contents-udeb-armel*' \
    --exclude 'Contents-udeb-armhf*' \
    --exclude 'Contents-udeb-i386*' \
    --exclude 'Contents-udeb-mips*' \
    --exclude 'Contents-udeb-mips64el*' \
    --exclude 'Contents-udeb-mipsel*' \
    --exclude 'Contents-udeb-ppc64el*' \
    --exclude 'Contents-udeb-s390x*' \
    -rtlvH \
    --safe-links \
    --bwlimit=${BWLIMIT} \
    --delete-after --progress \
    -h ${QUIET} \
    --timeout=600 \
    --contimeout=120 -p \
    --delay-updates \
    --no-motd \
    --temp-dir="${TMP}" \
    ${SOURCE} \
    "${TARGET}"
```

Comment: Since the contents of that github link may change over time, please import the actual updated script into the Answer here; thank you!

Comment: my script is too long but is link of the version : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liberodark/linux-mirroring/aa80213b4e089222558f801c5c2cda28cc4d8271/sync-debian.sh

Comment: I imported a copy of the script as of today. Note also that it's not a bash script, with a `#!/bin/sh` sh-bang line.

Answer (score 0):

You script looks fine to me (although I've not tried to run it), so you probably have a pattern mismatch. Looking in `ftp.fr.debian.org` I don't see anything called precisely `armhf`, for example, but I see lots of `Contents-armhf.gz` and `binary-armhf`, so I presume that these are what you are trying to exclude?

Try this:

```
rsync_exclude="$rsync_exclude --exclude *$item*"
```

So that the option becomes `--exclude *armhf*` (the asterisks should not get expanded in this example, but you'll need to add quotes to type that directly at a prompt).

If you are trying to update a local copy that already contains the other architectures then you should add `--delete-excluded`.